# PHP Create a .txt file with date as a filename

Tags: php, apache, fopen

Is it possible to use date as a filename when creating/opening one with fopen?
I have a form that writes user data to txt file, but I would like that everytime user submits info, new txt file is generated with date in file name.

Here is my try

```
$myfile='/home/myaccount/public_html/test/tiog/'.date('m-d-Y_hia').'.txt';
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $upisufajl);
fclose($fh);
```

Error I'm getting is

```
Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/...
```

And how could I encode it in UTF8, so that it supports special characters (čćšđž)?

Thanks

Comment: You can try using the meta method `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` --- `<meta charset="UTF-8">`, and encode the file itself as UTF-8, should do the trick.

Comment: my php script is in utf8, but txt files that itn creates are not

Comment: @JeremyStewart Then you will need to save those (.txt) as UTF-8 also. I use Notepad++ and it works well for me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that comment is misinformed...

Comment: @Christian What do you suggest then?

Comment: guys, script creates .txt files, not me by hand

Comment: @Christian Oh Btw, I was only referring to *"And how could I encode it in UTF8, so that it supports special characters (čćšđž)?"* and not the original question/problem. And it's what we call here "putting OUR heads together" and helping. ;-) I doubt I was misinforming the OP. Maybe not able to give ALL the answers, but didn't "misinform". UTF-8 is not an "exact" science, because there are too many variables at stake.

Comment: Actually, UTF-8 is pretty predictable, especially in a text file. A text file is simply plain text. Editors/viewers simply infer the kind of encoding by looking at some common patterns. But in essence an empty UTF-8 text file is exactly the same as an empty ASCII file. In fact, there's nothing that says it should contain text except my the file extension..

Comment: @Christian In a sense you're right, however I tend to differ on the fact that an empty UTF-8 and ASCII file are the same. If one (file) is encoded right off the bat as ASCII and characters needing to be encoded as UTF-8 are inserted, then it won't work. There could also be a byte order mark issue to also think about. I know this "first hand" and learnt that lesson the hard way.

Comment: I'll repeat; an empty file doesn't have anything that says what encoding it uses. You can't change the encoding of an empty file. What you advised above is simply to tell your editor/ide to write the file in a particular encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeremy, you are getting that error because your variable is misnamed:

```
$myfile= .... pen($myFile ....
   ^                 ^
   '-----------------'--------- see?
```

The second issue you have (regarding file encoding) is because text files are usually in plain ascii. If you want to save in UTF-8, it's perfectly fine...just make sure the string you are saving is in UTF-8.

Example:

```
file_put_contents($myfile, utf8_encode($upisufajl));
```

Comment: Please mark this as the right answer if it helped you out. :)